# Adding an element under the root in java

Tags: java, xml

```
I have an xml file that I'm parsing using json (function:convertXmlFileToDocument), then I'm getting xml validation rules from the database (function: getRulesByType).
```

and I'm doing two for loops to test if each element in the xml file, meets the validation criteria, such as mandatory.
Now if the the validation is correct on the xml file being validated, I need to add an element valid under the root. I tried this method:
/*Document.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("status"));
                    Document.setContent("valid");*/
                    but with no success. Any help on how to do so?

public void execute() throws Exception {

```
try{

    Document xmlDoc = convertXmlFileToDocument("c:\\TEST.xml");

    String xmlType = xmlDoc.getRootElement().getAttributeValue("type"); 
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hashValidationRules = getRulesByType(xmlType);

    HashMap<String, String> hashValidationRulesAtt = null;
    List<Element> childElem = xmlDoc.getRootElement().getChildren();
    List<Element> subChildElem = null;
    String elemName = "";
    String elemValue = "";
    boolean allIsOk = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < childElem.size(); j++) {

        subChildElem = childElem.get(j).getChildren();

        if(allIsOk){
            for (int j2 = 0; j2 < subChildElem.size(); j2++) {
                elemName = subChildElem.get(j2).getName();
                elemValue = subChildElem.get(j2).getValue();

                if(hashValidationRules.containsKey(elemName)){
                    hashValidationRulesAtt = hashValidationRules.get(elemName);
                    if(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("mandatory").equals("true") && (elemValue==null||elemValue.equals(""))){
                        allIsOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(elemValue.length()> Integer.parseInt(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("size"))){
                        allIsOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("format").equals("numeric")){
                        try {
                            Integer.parseInt(elemValue);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            allIsOk = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("format").equals("float")){
                        try {
                            Float.parseFloat(elemValue);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            allIsOk = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            /*Document.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("status"));
            Document.setContent("valid");*/
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!allIsOk){
        System.out.println("\n\n  ****Error****  \n\n");    
    }

}
finally {
    _Reader.endRead();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following will help , You can get the first child and append the element to it.

```
Document existingDocument = builder.parse(is);
Element statusOfTheDocument = existingDocument.createElement("status");
statusOfTheDocument.setTextContent("valid");
existingDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(statusOfTheDocument);
```